# NSURLCache and ETags with gzip enabled are not working

Tags: ios, caching, ios8, gzip, etag

I am trying to get NSURLCache to work on iOS8, but it seems to be broken when using an ETag and gzip compression. I am using NGINX with gzip compression enabled as a proxy for a thin webserver. The following response is not getting cached by NSURLCache:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server            nginx/1.7.6
Date              Thu, 06 Nov 2014 14:28:50 GMT
Content-Type      application/json;charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding chunked
Connection        keep-alive
Vary              Accept-Encoding
Cache-Control     private, max-age=0
ETag              W/"d693ff4d26d0e7f25498ecb89d8796cd41e9da4f"
Content-Encoding  gzip
```

When I disable gzip in the NGINX config, the request is cached correctly:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server         nginx/1.7.6
Date           Thu, 06 Nov 2014 14:26:40 GMT
Content-Type   application/json;charset=utf-8
Content-Length 311433
Connection     keep-alive
Cache-Control  private, max-age=0
ETag           W/"d693ff4d26d0e7f25498ecb89d8796cd41e9da4f"
```

I tried setting Cache-Control to public, but it did not help.

My setup with gzip enabled works perfectly on iOS7.

Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong? Or should I file a radar for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm on Apache and I'm really going mad on this too. I tried to set "gzip, deflate" for "Accept-Encoding" request header, I tried with NSUrlSession, simple URLRequest + URLConnection syncronous and asyncronous. The result is always the same. Caching works only if gzip/deflate and Vary are disabled on .htaccess for the requested file.

Comment: Hey, did you find any workaround to use gzip and etag?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, can't comment, missing reputation.

You can try delete all `-gzip` occurrences in the ETag. That is what works for my custom caching mechanism. Actually, I was searching for a proper way to tell `NSURLSession` to use gzip ETags. This feels like a workaround.